# Accessing an object anywhere in the application (C#/WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm deserializing an XML document into a custom object and I need that data to be available anywhere in the entire application.

I instantiate this public class in MainWindow.xaml.cs and I can't figure out how to access that object from other UserControls and ViewModels.

What are some best practices and examples?

Think of this object as holding all of my application's data that I want to be able to read from, update, and save from any screen. (Some of the data can be complex so I don't want to store it in settings. I need to read and write to the XML file.)

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using a static class instead?

Comment: Your question is too broad and also opinion based. There are several ways to do that, all of them with their advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: I can't implement INotifyPropertyChanged on a static class.

Comment: @dymanoid - Any examples? I just need to access data from anywhere. I have no opinion on how and I didn't state an opinion in my post.

Comment: Use a static class or add a resource to the `App` class: http://10rem.net/blog/2011/11/29/wpf-45-binding-and-change-notification-for-static-properties

Comment: The question is opinion based not because of _your_ opinion. It's opinion based because many developers will have many opinions how to implement this. There is no "best way" or "most recommended way". It all depends on many factors.

Comment: Well, using a static class is the most straightforward way. Though you have to take care to emit property changed events manually at e. g. config reload. Another approach is the service locator pattern.

Comment: @Nicolas, and a singleton, and a DI container, etc. It's all opinion based.

Comment: Or using a simple singleton pattern - create a static class that returns a new instance of your class if it was not yet created or return the created one (cached) so everyone will get the same instance and can access it from anywhere

Comment: @dymanoid, IMHO its not that opinion based to ask for experiences with `INotifyPropertyChanged` in this context, as it is difficult to see in advance what alternative works best with it. INotifyPropertyChanged was not mentioned in the question though... :/

Comment: How can you deserialize an XML file into a static class? I have to get the data from the XML file into a custom class.

Comment: Using a [Singleton Pattern](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) is probably exactly what you need.

Comment: @Icemanind - Doesn't a singleton require a static class? If so, how can I deserialize an XML document into it if serialization cannot occur on a static class?

Comment: @TGK You don't have to serialize the static class, but the static class (or the singleton) can hold/provide the deserialized object. Either manually (e. g. s. th. like `StaticClass.LoadXml()`) or via first access to the singleton, the XML data is loaded then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by e. g. implement a static class that manages your custom implementation, including serialization/deserialization.

```
public static class Config
{
    public static YourCustomType Data { get; private set; }

    public static void LoadXml()
    {
        Data = YourDeserializationLogic();
    }

    public static void SaveXml()
    {
        YourSerializationLogic(Data);
    }
}
```

And if you want to use the full power of notify change propagation, you may consider using separate properties of type `ObservableCollection<T>` in your static class:

```
public static ObservableCollection<AnotherCustomType> ObservableData  { get; private set; } = new ObservableCollection<AnotherCustomType>();
```

Just be sure that in your `LoadXml()` logic you have to populate these properties item by item, for the ObservableCollection to emit events:

```
public static void LoadXml()
{
    ...

    foreach (YourType item in YourData)
    {
        ObservableData.Add(item);
    }
}
```

---

I favor this option compared to e. g. a singleton, because I have full control of when in the startup sequence `Config.LoadWhatever()` is called.

<sub>This is important for me, because I like to have logging for the configuration load (which may be implemented via singleton as well, yes - but IMHO the principle of singletons is void, if the respective instances are always created in a fix place in the startup sequence - though I am happy to learn additional advantages if there are some).</sub>

Comment: I do like this approach! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What I have done is use a service that holds current data or whatever you want to call it. I inject it into the classes as a singleton so all classes have the same reference. In web client side it's referred to as a data store.